Is empty lines between make commands in a make target allowed?
I read this question about make grammar but still have one question:
Is it allowed to have completely empty lines as part of command sequence of a target? This Makefile (with TAB instead of spaces as indent, and the 3rd line containing no TAB character.)
boo:
        echo "foo"

        echo "bar"

vim marks the first echo as syntax group makeCommands and the second echo (after the empty line) as no group at all (so no syntax highlighting). Is this "legal" Make? Is this a mistake in vim's interpretation of Make?

Blank lines are allowed in target rules by POSIX:

lines that begin with a <tab>, are makefile command lines to be executed to update the target. The first non-empty line that does not begin with a <tab> or # shall begin a new entry.


Does that mean that a line that contains only a <tab> should be interpreted as an "empty" command (similar to pressing <enter> on an empty shell prompt)?

@Moberg, a line containing only a <tab> is an ordinary recipe line.  The effect of executing it is roughly equivalent to you running sh -c "" on the command line, which, yes, executes an empty command.

Yes, they are allowed. This is not an interpretation of Make by vim. If something is wrong with auto indent or syntax highlighting you should try watching your vim's plugins and dotfiles, maybe you are missing something.

This is with default vim syntax file for Make. I have reported the issue to Make syntax maintainer.
